# Java Byte comparison

Tags: java

I have a very simple below code where there are 2 variables:

```
ArrayList<Byte> randomArrayList = new ArrayList<Byte> (); 
Byte currentNumber;
```

Both of Byte class type.

Why is the below comparison not working. It always says both the numbers are different though I checked from debugger that they are same.

```
if (currentNumber.equals(randomArrayList.get(j)))
```

even `==` did not work.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

    // This is a main business logic class
    public class LottoLogic {

        public ArrayList<Byte> generateSixNumbers()
        {
            ArrayList<Byte> randomArrayList = new ArrayList<Byte> (); 
            byte currentNumber;

            for(int i=0;i <6;i++)
            {

                currentNumber = generate();

                for (int j = i-1; j>=0; j--)
                {                  

                    if (currentNumber == (byte) ( randomArrayList.get(j)))
                    {               
                        do
                        {
                            currentNumber = generate();
                        }while(currentNumber != randomArrayList.get(j));
                    }

                }

                randomArrayList.add(currentNumber);

            }

            randomArrayList = sort (randomArrayList);
            return randomArrayList;
        }

//      public byte[] generateSixNumbersAsArray(){
//          byte[] myArrayList;
//          for (int i )
//          myArrayList[i] = 
//      }

        public byte generate()
        {
            byte randomNumber = (byte) ((Math.random()*48)+1);
            return randomNumber;
        }

        public ArrayList<Byte> sort (ArrayList<Byte> myList)
        {
            Collections.sort(myList);
            return myList;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you show a little program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Because the values don't match. Too little code to guess the actual issue. Try printing out `currentNumber` and `randomArrayList.get(j)`.

Comment: ArrayList<Byte> randomArrayList = new ArrayList<Byte> (); 
   Byte currentNumber;
  
   for(int i=0;i <6;i++)
   {
    
    currentNumber = generate();
         
    for (int j = i-1; j>=0; j--)
    {          
          
     if (currentNumber.equals(randomArrayList.get(j)))
     {          
      do
      {
       currentNumber = generate();
      }while(currentNumber != randomArrayList.get(j));
     }
          
    }
    
    randomArrayList.add(currentNumber);
      
   }

Comment: What attempts have you made to debug this?

Comment: Post full example including the variable values you are using for that if statement.

Comment: @Sam We can't see your debugger. The piece of code you provided is not enough to answer your question.

Comment: In doubt you have the infamous ; after the if statement

Comment: I am not sure how to add code. I hope you guys can see it. I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: You've got two logic statements that can never both be true at the same time:  `if (currentNumber.equals(randomArrayList.get(j)))` followed by a do..while loop with the opposite condition (`currentNumber != randomArrayList.get(j)`).

Comment: Are you trying to make a list of random, non-repeating bytes?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I got the problem. One is byte and other is Byte. How can i compare these two?

Comment: `Byte` has a constructor that takes a `byte` argument

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that creates a list of random, non-repeating Bytes.. I think that's what you're trying for (**EDIT**: assume generate() returns a `byte`, instead of `Byte`:

```
    ArrayList<Byte> myBytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
    Byte currentByte = new Byte(generate());
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        while(myBytes.contains(currentByte)){
            currentByte=generate();
        }
        myBytes.add(currentByte);
    }
    for(Byte b : myBytes) {
        System.out.println(Byte.toString(b));
    }
```

Comment: Can I have in your example currentByte is byte instead of Byte? Will it still work ?

Comment: I've updated the code to assume that `generate()` returns a `byte`.  Note that with autoboxing I think you can get away with comparing a `Byte` to a `byte`, but it's good form to have them both the same type.

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing us enough code.

I've used your example to make the following, which works

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<Byte> randomArrayList = new ArrayList<Byte>();
    Byte currentNumber;

    randomArrayList.add((byte) 12);
    currentNumber = 12;

    int j = 0;

    if (currentNumber.equals(randomArrayList.get(j)))
    {
        System.out.println("Equals");
    }
}
```

I'll update the answer if you give us more information

Comment: I have added code now.