# Byte comparision in java

Tags: java, hex, byte

what actually happens here, when `byte - byte` is occur?
suppose,

```
byteResult = byte1 - byte2;
```

where,

```
byte1 = 0xff;
byte2 = 0x01;
```

then,
is `byte1` turns into integer with value 255 and and `byte2` 1 and `byteResult` assigned to 254 then converted into `byte` with `0xFE`? And then the `if` condition is checked? Please a detail help will be very helpful for me. Sorry if my question is ambiguous! 
Here, I found something but not what exactly I want.
[Java Byte comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983111/java-byte-comparison/)

Comment: in java, primitive types are signed, so byte range is supposed to be [-128..127] not [0..255], isn't it?

Comment: "is byte1 turns into integer with value 255 " <-- no, it will be -1 when cast to int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the byte will not be converted into an int.

From the [JLS 5.2 Assignment Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of
>   type **byte**, short, char, or int: - A narrowing primitive conversion may
>   be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the
>   value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the
>   variable.

Also check **[subtracting 2 bytes makes int?](https://community.oracle.com/message/5099419)**

This is a basic premise of Java programming. All integers are of type int unless specifically cast to another type. Therefore, any arithmetic done with integers automatically 'promotes' all the operands to int type from the narrower type (byte, short), and the result of arithmetic with int operands is always int. (I think I've beaten that to death now).

If you want the short result of arithmetic with two bytes, do this:

```
short result = (short) (byte1 - byte2)
```

This explicit cast makes it the programmer's responsibility for throwing away the extra bits if they aren't needed. Otherwise, integer arithmetic is done in 32 bits.